# Parsing subchilds in XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

Im trying to extract information from a XML-document with ElementTree in Python 3.2.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Page Id="1">
    <Group>4</Group>
    <Type>
        <Letter>B</Letter>
        <Number>101</Number>
        <Deep>
            <A>900</A>
            <B>900</B>
        </Deep>
    </Type>
</Page>
```

I manage to get the elementdata from "Group" with:

```
for Page in root.iter('Page'):
     Group = Page.find('Group').text
```

And "Letter"-data with:

```
for Type in root.iter('Type'):
     Dim = Type.find('Letter').text
```

However I can't figure out how to get the data from the subchilds of "Deep" (A and B).
All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. Use `find` to find the `Deep` tag and the iterate over it.

**Ex:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
for Type in root.iter('Type'):
    for deep_tag in Type.find("Deep"):
        print( deep_tag.text )
```

**Output:**

```
900
900
```

Comment: Quick little follow up question: Sometimes only A is present and sometimes only B. In those cases I need to know if 900 is from "A" or "B". Do you know a way to print these out as well?

Comment: `print( deep_tag.text, deep_tag.tag )`